# ruby rails edit attribute using a button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Suppose I have an object @transaction that gets shown /transactions/id

```
def show
    @transaction = Transaction.find(params[:id]);
end
```

In show.html.erb, I want to have a button that when pressed changes one of the attributes of Transaction. How do I do that?

In show.html.erb, I have

```
<%= form_for @transaction do |t| %>
    <%= t.label :id %> : <%= @transaction.id %><br />

    <%= t.submit "pay" %>
<% end %>
```

EDIT: I think I may have misled with the question. The button code above generates this html:

```
<input id="transaction_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="pay" />
```

When I click on the button, the "update" method in the controller is called. How do I pass the value from a button to a specific action in the update method? For example, suppose `button1`changes the transaction.name to "lalala". How do I do this?

```
def update
  // if button1 is pressed, change transaction.name to lalala
  // if button2 is pressed, change transaction.amount to bobobo
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a different form for each button:

```
 <%= form_for @transaction do |t| %>
     <%= t.hidden_field :name, :value=>"mike" %>
     <%= t.submit "change_name_to_mike" %>
   <% end %>

   <%= form_for @transaction do |t| %>
     <%= t.hidden_field :name, :value=>"john" %>
     <%= t.submit "change_name_to_john`" %>
   <% end %>
```

Comment: I think `link_to` would be a much better and elegant way to write this..?

Comment: It's not that much more work--see the link to my blog post in my answer; Rails makes stuff like that super-easy.

Comment: I also have the same requirement but I want to do it for a `ticker` you can say an increment. once the button is clicked the value is increased by `1`. Can you explain the line `<t.hidden_field :name :value =>"john %>`  I dint quite understand why `"` were kept in it. Thanks!

Comment: :value=>"john and :value=>"mike need an " each. I have just updated my answer and added the closing ".
For a ticker it would be straight forward, just pass :value=>"1" and increment the variable in the controller instead of assigning it. 
Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

Or do it via Ajax. For example, you could have a `link_to "Delete votes", delete_votes_path(user), :remote => true` (or whatever). The action can then do whatever it needs to, and possibly return JavaScript that will update a div/span/whatever with the new value, as well as display a message, and so on.

This is a bit more elegant, and Rails makes it pretty easy to create little bits of Ajaxy functionality that ramp up the UX, but take little effort. Trivial, naive example [here](http://buckybits.blogspot.com/2011/09/simple-ajax-property-toggle-in-rails-30.html).